# Karaf and persistence unit: Missing dependencies: JpaTemplate

Tags: jpa, osgi, eclipselink, karaf

I was fighting to install JPA and start persistence unit on Karaf 4.0.8 container. I've installed:

```
feature:install webconsole
feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/jpa-features/2.5.0/xml/features
feature:install jpa/2.5.0
feature:install transaction-api/1.2.0
feature:install transaction
feature:install eclipselink
```

My bundle with persistence unit starts, but it doesn't export any services. The bundle that uses it and imports JpaTemplate fails to import service:

```
<reference id="jpaTemplate" interface="org.apache.aries.jpa.template.JpaTemplate" filter="(osgi.unit.name=officialUnit)" />
```

which should be exported from my persistence bundle, but it is not. 'diag' shows no problem with persistence bundle.

How to debug why the persistence unit is not correctly started?

My persistence.xml looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="officialUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <!-- Only used when transaction-type=JTA -->
        <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=demo-db)</jta-data-source>

        <!-- Only used when transaction-type=RESOURCE_LOCAL -->
        <non-jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=demo-db)</non-jta-data-source>

        <class>example.entity.SomeEntity</class>    

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="sql-script" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The configuration file `etc/org.ops4j.datasource-sqlitetest.cfg` :

```
osgi.jdbc.driver.name=sqlite
url=jdbc:sqlite:D:/data/db/demo.db
dataSourceName=demo-db
```

And the `MANIFEST.MF` of persistence bundle:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1486560203107
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
Bundle-Description: Persistence
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: example.persistence.impl
Bundle-SymbolicName: example.persistence.impl
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: example.persistence.impl;version="1.0.0";uses:="javax.pe
 rsistence,javax.xml.bind.annotation"
Import-Package: javax.persistence;version="[2.1,3)",javax.xml.bind.annot
 ation
Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
Originally-Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Provide-Capability: osgi.service;effective:=active;objectClass="org.apac
 he.aries.jpa.supplier.EmSupplier";osgi.unit.name=officialUnit,osgi.serv
 ice;effective:=active;objectClass="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFacto
 ry";osgi.unit.name=officialUnit,osgi.service;effective:=active;objectCl
 ass="org.apache.aries.jpa.template.JpaTemplate";osgi.unit.name=official
 Unit,osgi.service;effective:=active;objectClass="javax.persistence.Enti
 tyManager";osgi.unit.name=officialUnit
Require-Capability: osgi.service;effective:=active;objectClass="javax.sq
 l.DataSource";filter:="(osgi.jndi.service.name=demo-db)",osgi.service;e
 ffective:=active;objectClass="javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
 ";javax.persistence.provider="org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistencePr
 ovider",osgi.extender;osgi.extender="aries.jpa",osgi.service;effective:
 =active;objectClass="javax.transaction.TransactionManager",osgi.ee;filt
 er:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-3.2.0.201605172007
```

The persistent unit was successfully started in Eclipse using OSGi Framework launch configuration.

Comment: Can you give the logs and the content of your persistence.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jpa is not trivial to debug as there are many moving parts. The first step is to check if your persistence bundle is found by aries jpa container at all.

First thing to check is if the Manifest of your persitence unit bundle has the Meta-Persistence header and points to the persistence.xml like: META-INF/persistence.xml.

If you have this then jpa container should pick up the bundle and parse your persistence.xml.

Next things to check is if the PersistenceProvider service is present and if the DataSource is present (if you use a DataSource).

If you configure your DataSource using a config then do not forget to install the necessary pax-jdbc features:

```
feature:repo-add pax-jdbc 1.0.0
feature:install pax-jdbc-config pax-jdbc-sqlite
```

Comment: First thing: yes - see my edit>
Next: Configuration file is read, I see it in WebConsole. My bundle works in Eclipse OSGi Framework launch configuration. Now I try to configure runtime environment for Karaf.

Comment: You are using a data source configuration from pax jdbc. This means you also need to install the features pax-jdbc-config and pax-jdbc-sqlite. After that check if your ds config is read and check if a DataSource is created.

Comment: Thank you. Please include your comment about pax-jdbc-config and pax-jdbc-sqlite, because it was the missing part in my case.